# Can I also get French citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, french-citizens

My grandfather had French citizenship. But my father doesn't.
Am I eligible for French citizenship based on my [grand]father's citizenship. How to apply?

Comment: Since your father never exercised his right of French citizenship (assuming your grandfather was French at the time of his birth), you are **not**  eligible for French citizenship.

Comment: @Shyam Sundar Have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_nationality_law?

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's extremely likely but not necessarily so. What's relevant is how long both have lived abroad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grandfather served in the French army for 4.5 years: Can I get French nationality?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/grandfather-served-in-the-french-army-for-4-5-years-can-i-get-french-nationalit)

Comment: If your father was French when you were born then you might be French yourself. If he wasn't then you aren't. No way around that, your grand-father's citizenship is not relevant as such. The problem is that it sounds like nobody in your family made use of their French citizenship in the last 50 years (and I assume you do not live in France). In that case, you cannot regain French citizenship. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/grandfather-served-in-the-french-army-for-4-5-years-can-i-get-french-nationalit provides more details.