# French Citizenship and article 30-3 of the Civil Code

Tags: immigration, france, french-citizens, international-law

My father was born to a French woman but adopted shortly after birth by Americans. My father died young, before the expiration of the 50 year restriction mentioned in 30-3 of the civil code. I am only 30 years old. My question is, will this 50 year limit still pertain to my father, even though he died well before 50 years expired?

Comment: See also https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21607/about-losing-french-nationality-by-not-using/21608#21608 and especially https://www.doctrine.fr/d/TGI/Paris/2018/FR0FDDBD294B26FF820234

Answer (score 2):

Some courts decisions I read when preparing my answer to [Will it be possible to get French citizenship?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6618/will-it-be-possible-to-get-french-citizenship/6619#6619) suggests that the 50-year delay is counted from the date you try to get your citizenship recognised. Even if the wording of article 30-3 is slightly different, that's also what article 23-6 suggests.

Under this interpretation, the question becomes “Has your father held ‘*possession d'état*’ or resided in France in the last fifty years?” and the answer is clearly no, even if he was already dead during some part of that period.

Comment: Thank for this very informed response. Would it make any difference if my natural grandmother still lives in France?

Comment: The reason I ask is because 23(6) states that my father would have lost citizenship only if the parent from whom he acquired french nationality had no residence in France for half a century.

Comment: Also, does this answer my original question: http://www.assemblee-afe.fr/deces-de-l-ascendant-avant-ses-50.html? Here it says that for a parent who died before the 50 years, the time is counted, for the children, from the date of the ascendant's death. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @Emmanuel The question is almost identical but unfortunately the answer is not very helpful. The language is very guarded “il *semble* que” and the last paragraph basically says that only the courts can decide.

Comment: Yes, you're right--that's why I ask. Where can I go to read the court decisions that you read?

Comment: @Emmanuel To be honest, I just recall reading about this, perhaps from second-hand sources. Unfortunately, I didn't keep any reference, sorry... As far as I remember, they did not deal with a situation where the French citizen died before reaching the age of 50.