Father born in the US to parents that were French citizens. Am I eligible to apply for French citizenship by descent?
I am trying to find out if there is a pathway for me to obtain French citizenship. My father was born in the US however both of his parents were French Citizens. Most of his older siblings were born in France. I am trying to find out if his birth was registered in France but am having difficulty. He passed away recently.

Did your father actively use his French citizenship and can you prove that? For example did he obtain and renew a French passport or vote in French elections?

This question is similar to: Will it be possible to get French citizenship?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Traveller The answer to the other question does describe all applicable law but there is a small caveat that makes it difficult to consider it a true duplicate: Tunisia was a French protectorate for much of the 20th century. Ultimately it doesn't count as French territory for nationality purposes but it often confuses people, cf. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21607/about-losing-french-nationality-by-not-using
