Mother naturalized in US in 1951. Was a French citizen. I was born in 1952. Can I claim French citizenship?
My mother was born in France in 1925.  She emigrated to the U.S. in 1948 and naturalized in 1951 after she married my father, an American citizen.  I was born in 1952.  Any idea if I can claim French citizenship?  I was born in the U.S.

Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6618/will-it-be-possible-to-get-french-citizenship

Is your mother still alive? I assume she isn't but otherwise, she would still be a French citizen and able to help you claim yours (e.g. by applying for a passport).

You were almost certainly born a French citizen but it is highly unlikely that you would still be allowed to make use of your citizenship.
Historically, marrying a foreign citizen could lead a woman to lose her French citizenship but this was abolished in 1927. When she married your father and became an American citizen in 1951, your mother therefore remained a French citizen. If you go back even further in time, French citizenship would only be transmitted by males but it definitely wasn't the case anymore in 1952 so as the daughter of a French citizen, you were born a French citizen.
Assuming both your mother and yourself have lived in the US (or outside France) since 1952 then it comes down to whether either of you made use of that citizenship, meaning doing something like voting or renewing a passport (legally: whether you had “possession d'état“, i.e. did something that implies the French state implicitly recognized you as a citizen). Unless you can produce proof of that (e.g. a French passport from the 1980s), your French citizenship would have lapsed after 50 years, in 1998 or 2002 (not sure exactly what date counts but it's now moot).

Under certain circumstances including permanent residency, you could apply for French citizenship in your own right, but you have no inherited right to clain citizenship because (a) your mother was already a naturalised US citizen at the time of your birth, and (b) you were not born in France or spent a significant part of your life in France. If you had any official French paperwork, such as a French birth certificate from a French issuing authority, it would possibly help, but this would appear not to be the case.

Perhaps surprisingly, when and whether the mother was naturalised is irrelevant. The assumption is presumably that someone who doesn't have any other citizenship would regularly renew their French passport and article 30-3 of the code civil could not possibly apply as they would maintain possession d'état de Français.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
